# Installing WSO2 Stratos 1.6.0 on Windows

Tags: windows, wso2

Any one tried installing WSO2 Stratos 1.6.0 on windows or is it possible to install and run on windows 7 or windows 8?

I believe that install and run script are shell script for Unix/Linux only.

Would it be possible to run/execute same using cygwin or Cooperative Linux (also known as CoLinux)?

thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The Stratos 1.6.0 has WSO2 products and each product is configured to work in a cluster. There are few scripts to setup initial databases etc. The Stratos 1.6.0 mainly uses the in-built multi-tenant features of WSO2 products to offer a PaaS.

It's possible to run WSO2 Stratos 1.6.0 on Windows. WSO2 products can run on Windows since it depends only on Java runtime.

The installation scripts were given only for Linux environments as it was tested on Linux. However you can try to execute those using cygwin or go through the script and manually do each configuration on your Windows environment.

Please note that you will get old products from Stratos 1.6.0.

As mentioned by [Manula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429035/1955702), we no longer release WSO2 Stratos. The Stratos project introduced major changes in version 2.0. It mainly introduced the concept of cartridges. This means that the latest Stratos can run any application on any run-time, such as PHP.

The [Stratos 2.0 project was donated to Apache Foundation](http://bit.ly/17r7rqn) and it's important to note that [Apache Stratos (incubating)](http://stratos.incubator.apache.org/) project is a PaaS framework and it's totally different to Stratos 1.6.0.

When you get Apache Stratos (incubating) project, you will not get any WSO2 products as Cartridges.

We plan to release [WSO2 Private PaaS](http://bit.ly/1myTrj6), which will include the [Apache Stratos (incubating)](http://stratos.incubator.apache.org/) PaaS framework and WSO2 Products as cartridges. Basically the replacement for Stratos 1.6.0 will be the upcoming WSO2 Private PaaS product.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Apache Stratos and WSO2 Private PaaS seem to be promising stack for future prospects. Is there any timeline set or expectation when would it be released or even beta / early testing?
Also, while it is being developed, would it be possible to set Carbon server with WSO2 products feature installed. As mentioned in my initial question, I tried to configure feature with Carbon server it but I could not get it installed as feature.

Comment: How we develop paas application on wso2 cloud?.and why we need apache stratos for that?.can you help me to create simple pass application on wso2 cloud using stratos?.I,m new to opensource cloud

Answer (score 0):

Stratos 1.6.0 is the older version. Now the ongoing version is Apache Stratos 4.0. You can find more details of it from [1]. If you are trying with stratos please move to Apache Stratos.

[1] http://stratos.incubator.apache.org/

Thanks !
ManulaC

Comment: Thanks for your reply Manula, I am looking for preloaded bundle like what Stratos 1.6.0 with WSO2 middleware components.

I believe that Apache Stratos 4.0 is do not contain any of the middleware component from WSO2 and there are no reference available using which one can configure on local setup as well. It would great if you can share reference material on setting Apache Stratos 4.0 with WSO2 middleware component.